# Can I safely mine and sell all the Beacon blocks after the first quest to find 2 of them?

Tags: super-motherload

In the game [Super Motherload](http://store.steampowered.com/app/269110/) there is a quest to find two Beacon blocks, after that they become mineable normal blocks, should I keep some for later quests, or can I mine and sell them all ?

[image]

Comment: Since I havent played this game in a while I shall leave this as a comment, but to the best of my knowledge selling them after you have completed the first quest is fine as I do not remember another quest for becons coming in after that

Comment: @Mr.Burns Thanks! I started mining them, and I will probably write an answer after I finished the game